# Remainders and polynomial division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Completley impromptu, one of my extended middle school students asked a question about her additional maths she was studying outside of school.

For a certain polynomial, f(x), the remainder on division by $(x-1)^2$ is $(2x-1)$, and $f(x)$ leaves a remainder of $1$  on division by $(x-3)$.  Find the remainder on division by $(x-1)^2(x-3)$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $f(x)=g(x)(x-1)^2(x-3)+A(x-1)^2+B(x-3)+C$

Using [Polynomial remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem), $1=f(3)=4A+C\iff C=-4A$

and $f(x)\equiv Bx+C-3B\pmod{(x-1)^2}\implies B=2,C-3B=-1\iff C=?$

Comment: Isn't $f(3)=1$? "...f(x) leaves a remainder of 1 on division by (x−3)."

Comment: @user31782, Sorry for the typo.